# Create python module

Tags: python, pip, python-module, pyproject.toml

I would like to create a python module, this the the structure of my project (I have shown the minimal of it)

```
.
├── code/
│   └── main.py
└── pyproject.toml
```

and this is my `pyproject.toml` file

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["flit_core >=3.2,<4"]
build-backend = "flit_core.buildapi"

[tool.flit.module]
name = "code"

[project]
name = "my_module_name"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "Foobar"
readme = "README.md"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]
requires-python = ">=3.0"
dependencies = [
    "foo >=1.2.3",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/foo/bar"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/foo/bar/issues"
```

When I run `pip install git+https://github.com/foo/bar.git` it successfully install the module
But when I write `from my_module_name import code`, I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module_name'` error

How can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect `from code import main` might work: usually I see the directory next to `pyproject.toml` called `my_module_name`. You can debug with `help("modules")` in the REPL.

Comment: Yes, I added [tool.flit.module] to indicate that the codes are in code directory. but I'm not sure if it's correct. there is no `my_module_name` in the `help("modules")` output

Comment: That's only going to affect the `flit` tool. If you're not going to do it the "normal" way, this is a flit-specific question. (I don't know much about flit.)

Comment: [The documentation](https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/pyproject_toml.html) reckons the module would be exposed as `code`: “If your package will have different names for installation and import, you should specify the install (PyPI) name in the `[project]` table ([see above](https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/pyproject_toml.html#pyproject-toml-project)), and the import name in a `[tool.flit.module]` table:”

Comment: ValueError: No file/folder found for module my_module_name

Comment: The module's file / folder name needs to be the same as how you want it imported (unless there's a feature of `flit` I don't know about, which is possible).

Comment: is there any option other that `flit` that you are familiar with and it can solve my problem?

Comment: I mean, you could write your own build system. Apart from that, I think the only solution is renaming that folder.